# In PHP, If string exists in array, add '-1', '-2', etc, until unique

Tags: php, arrays, string

In PHP, I need to check if a string exists in an Array. If it does, a '-1' should be added to its value, if  'string-1' exists again, then it should be 'string-2' etc. until 'string-N' will be unique.

```
$string = 'string';
If $string exists in $array, $string = 'string-1'
If $string exists again in $array, $string = 'string-2'
If $string exists again in $array, $string = 'string-3'
etc
```

Comment: Can you paste array structure with data ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$filearray = //blah blah ... (you need to have this array filled before)
$filename = "string";
if (in_array($filename,$filearray))
{
    $i = 1;
    while (in_array($filename.'-'.$i,$filearray))
    {
        i++;
    }
    $filename = $filename.'-'.$i;
}
echo $filename;
```

Comment: Looks like a good guess for the actual use case ;) depending on how the array got filled, maybe `file_exists` is better suited than `in_array`, but that's guessing again.

Comment: @feb, I am not sure what he was trying to do. Just guessing. Actually from windows explorer behavior. :) 
But isn't running of scandir() one time better than running file_exists() multiply times?!

Comment: That *might* depend on the total number of files, but I don't think so. One lookup in the file system is very fast, no need to scan the whole directory.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work... Is it because my array is multidimensional?

Comment: @Denn of course it is because your array is multidimensional. You should told us this before. Please show us an example from your array and we will change our codes to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$array = array("this", "is", "my", "string", "and", "it", "is", "a", "string");
$string = "string";

$i = 1;
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    if ($value == $string) {
        $value = $string . "-" . ($i++);
    }
}
unset($value);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => this
    [1] => is
    [2] => my
    [3] => string-1
    [4] => and
    [5] => it
    [6] => is
    [7] => a
    [8] => string-2
)
```

Comment: I don't think that was meant with "exists again".

Answer (score 1):

A perfect use case for while-loops:

```
$tmp = $string;
$i = 1;
while(in_array($tmp, $array)) {
    $tmp = $string . '-' . $i;
    ++$i;
}
$string = $tmp;
```

Example:

```
$string = 'test';
$array = ['foo', 'bar', 'test', 'test-1'];
```

Output:

```
test-2
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to append -1, -2... after every string in the array if it has more than one occurrence. Check this code:

```
<?php

$array = array("this", "is", "my", "string", "and", "it", "is", "a", "string", "do", "you", "like", "my", "string");
$ocurrences = array();

$iterator = new ArrayIterator($array);

while ($iterator->valid()) {
    $keys = array_keys($ocurrences);
    if (in_array($iterator->current(), $keys)) {
        $array[$iterator->key()] = $iterator->current() . '-' . $ocurrences[$iterator->current()];
        $ocurrences[$iterator->current()]++;
    }
    else {
        $ocurrences[$iterator->current()] = 1;
    }
    $iterator->next();
}

print_r($array);
```

It will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => this
    [1] => is
    [2] => my
    [3] => string
    [4] => and
    [5] => it
    [6] => is-1
    [7] => a
    [8] => string-1
    [9] => do
    [10] => you
    [11] => like
    [12] => my-1
    [13] => string-2
)
```